# Google Web Master Tools - API and PHP PUT

Tags: php, google-search-console

I am trying to use Google Webmaster Tools API in PHP :)
I have managed to make functions for creating the site in my account.. but now I am trying to get Verification working...

Here is the Doc:
http://code.google.com/intl/hr-HR/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#AD_Verifying

So the problem is... In the docs says:
Then submit an authenticated PUT request to:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexample%2Ecom%2F/

But everything I have tried doesn't work... for example..

```
$method = strtoupper('put');
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => $method,
        'protocol_version' => 1.0,
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/atom+xml'."\n Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$auth."\n Content-Length: ".strlen($content),
        'content' => $content
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Anyone has some ideas how to make verification working? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$method = strtoupper($method);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => $method,
        'protocol_version' => 1.0,
        'header'  => 'Content-type: ' . $contentType .
                     (isset($this->auth) && isset($this->auth['Auth']) ? "\nAuthorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->auth['Auth']  : '' ) .
                     "\nContent-Length: " . strlen($content),
        'content' => $content
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
**$result = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);**
return $result;
```